# To Stop a Constructor

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement a sort of Constructor Pattern into a library for a project. But, I want to check for certain conditions being passed before returning an object. If those conditions aren't met, then I want to stop the constructor and return `false`.

But, I noticed that no matter what I set as the return value, an object is always returned!

Even if I do this:

```
new function () { return false; }
```

The result is still an `Object` object:

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome console]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox console]

**Is there any way to have a constructor fail in Javascript?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If those conditions aren't met, then I want to stop the constructor and return false.

You can't. The return value of a constructor function is ignored unless it's a non-`null` object. Any primitive value (or `null`) is just ignored by the `new` expression.

If you **really** want to have a flag value you return, you can do that, but it has to be an object. (But it's a bad idea, more below.) E.g.:

```
// The constructor
function Foo(num) {
    if (num < 27) {
        return Foo.BAD_ARG; // This is a bad idea, see the right way below
    }
    this.num = num;
}
Foo.BAD_ARG = {}; // Our special "bad argument" object
```

> Is there any way to have a constructor fail in Javascript?

Yes: Throw an exception:

```
function Foo(num) {
    if (num < 27) {
        throw "`num` must be >= 27";
    }
    this.num = num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I have a constructor with a `catch` block that isn't stopping the construction though. Can you look at http://pastebin.com/xnVmZ55Y and tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: @Martin: You don't want to catch the exception *in* the constructor, that's the whole point. You *throw* the exception within the constructor, which prevents the normal return, and thus prevents the calling code getting a reference to the newly-created object. You handle the exception in the code *calling* the constructor (or the code calling it, etc.), not in the constructor.

Comment: But wouldn't that just use up a lot of memory? I don't want an object to be created with extra flags to show it's useless.. I want to stop the construction altogether.

Something like this (http://pastebin.com/rcYTXTzq) would work, no?

Comment: @Martin: What memory? What flags? Just throw an exception in response to the exceptional condition. No significant memory impact, no special flags. The code calling the constructor either gets a proper, flag-free object, or gets an exception it has to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to return a non-object will be to wrap your constructor in a function and have it call (or not call) using `new` for you.

To do this, `new` on the outer function will need to be prohibited.

---

You can even use the same function, as long as you never call it with `new`.

```
function Foo() {
   if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
       if (some_condition)
           return false;
       else
           return new Foo()
   }
   // your constructor code here
}

var x = Foo();
```

The danger is if  you forget and accidentally use `new`. To remedy this, you can use a separate function.

```
function Foo() {
    // constructor code
}

function Bar() {
    if (this instanceof Bar)
        throw "Not a constructor"

    if (some_condition)
         return false;
    else
        return new Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Throw an error out of the stack, e.g.

```
function thing(){
    throw new Error('nope');
}

try {
    var mine = new thing();
}
catch( e ){
    mine = null;
}

// mine is null
```

You could also do a sort of factory method, like:

```
createThing = function(){
   var obj = new thing();
   if( obj.feelsOK ){
       return obj;
   }
}

mine = createThing();
// mine is null
```

Comment: This is what I ended up starting to do afterwards. But, T.J. Crowder's answer is closer to what I was looking for.